# Good podcasting solution?

Tags: joomla, podcast

***I simply ask for the best, most common and simple way to set up a podcast? Please, I need an answer so I can close this question?***

---

I run a joomla-based website for a small church and now need a simple, cheap and effective solution for an audio podcast.
I am looking for a solution that will do the following:

- User uploads audio files to service (preferably not to our own site) that is cheap, fast and simple to use. Dropbox for example?
- Files are easily embeddable into Joomla website articles to be played on the spot (through simple-to-use and media player). Preferably through RSS feeds (to make it easy to update every week).
- Files are downloadable.
- Files are viewable on iPhones and other smartphones.
- Solution can be broadcasted via iTunes.
- Solution doesn't need a lot of extra, new third party software. I'd rather keep it simple and familiar than have it be a complete new system but with a steep learning curve.

At the moment we use vimeo to host the podcast, through video files. But we'd like to move to something simpler that doesn't involve a series of difficult steps to upload the files to the web.

Comment: I would, but I haven't gotten a good answer yet.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using [podomatic](http://www.podomatic.com/): I've used it before and it works well, but it's not a self-hosted solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can upload your podcasts to [archive.org](http://www.archive.org).

http://www.archive.org/about/faqs.php#Uploading_Content